# "Sign in to WI-FI network" & "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: samsung

Problem is that this occured to my phone, I could not access the internet with my phone but it is fine with other devices. So I am quite sure that it is not the router. It's so weird because awhile ago it was working then after a few minutes after reluctantly trying to forget the network and put the password again and again. There it was  " Sign in to WI-FI network". Then i pressed it and loads. 500 Internal Server appeared. I've tried changing the ip setting, but it still led me to the Internal Server problem. I've tried everthing on the internet but I'm still hopeless.